# ARIA role='log' Is it relevant to use a narrating ghost div for an accessible HTML game?

Tags: javascript, html, terminal, wai-aria

I'm developing an HTML game with a textual interface and i want to make it accessible.

To have a rpg dialog effect, the text appear in a typewriter way - with latency added on spaces.

I use a recursive Javascript function to do that :

- if it is a space then `setTimeout(f,time_between_words)`,
- if is a standard char then it plays sound and `setTimeout(f,time_for_a_char)`.

The problem is that, the focus not follow smoothly with a screen reader.

When Orca read the text, then it repeats the sentences [length of the text] times : "i" ,"it", "it i", "it is", "it is a", "it is an"...

Maybe I could make worlds appear with CSS (as a block of text) but the rythm is quite hard to describe with CSS (as much as it is to time the sounds - with many delayed keyframes).

The solution I found to put a "ghost" div containing a the text to be read by the screen reader.

```
<body>
  <div id="ghost-monitor" role="log" aria-live="polite">
    A long long time ago [what the screen reader read]
    [text added block by block, with <br> to end line]
  </div>
</body>
```

The (simplified) function for showing messages is the following :

```
var mon=document.getElementById("ghost-monitor");
function show_msg (txt,el){
    /*
     * Message lively shown character by character
     */
    var msg=document.createElement('p');
    el.appendChild(msg);
    txttab=txt.split('');
    //recursively display characters one by one with setTimeout 
    t._show_chars(t.msg_idx,msg,txttab);

    /*
     * Message spoken by screen reader
     */
    var ghostmsg=document.createElement('p');
    mon.appendChild(ghostmsg);
    ghostmsg.innerHTML=txt.replace('\n',"<br>").replace(/«»/,'"');
}
```

So the solution, in this case, is to duplicate the live content in order to have a specific part for people unable to read with eyes.

The solution seems ugly, do you know another way to deal ?